# Ember Nested Routing

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In my application.hbs want to:

```
{{#linkTo 'pieces/newPiece' }}New Piece{{/linkTo}}
```

So I set up the router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('pieces', function(){
    this.route('newPiece');
  });
});
```

Yet I get:

```
The route pieces/newPiece was not found
```

Any direction appreciated

**UPDATE**

I changed:

```
{{#linkTo 'pieces/newPiece' }}New Piece{{/linkTo}}
```

to

```
{{#linkTo 'pieces.newPiece' }}New Piece{{/linkTo}},
```

and that took care of the error, but what I want is to call the 'newPiece' function of the piecesController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [`{{action}}` helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/) for that.  From the guide:

> You may want to trigger high level events in response to a simple user
>   event (like a click).
>
> In general, these events will manipulate some property on the
>   controller, which will change the current template via bindings.

In your case, assuming that `pieces` is the current controller in context you would use:

```
<a href='#' {{action newPiece}}>New Piece</a>
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/oyobey/2/edit)